# File is not downloading while using chrome headless browser

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome-headless

I am using headless chrome driver. I don't see any files in desired location after clicking on file download options. however, download is working fine without headless. Please find the ChromeOptions and DesiredCapabilities that i m using

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 2);
prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
prefs.put("download.default_directory", System.getProperty("user.dir")+File.separator+"download");

ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless", "window-size=1024,768", "--no-sandbox");   
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); 
    chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
    chromeOptions.addArguments("disable-popup-blocking");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
    caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
```

Comment: give a try removing the headless argument

Comment: can you show your automation code as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a quick google for you and led to https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=696481 which suggests to use

Page.setDownloadBehavior. Something like (below) : Disclaimer: Copying verbatim

```
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver");
                    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                    options.addArguments("--test-type");
                    options.addArguments("--headless");
                    options.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); //to disable browser extension popup

                    ChromeDriverService driverService = ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService();
                    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(driverService, options);

                    Map<String, Object> commandParams = new HashMap<>();
                    commandParams.put("cmd", "Page.setDownloadBehavior");
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                    params.put("behavior", "allow");
                    params.put("downloadPath", "//home//vaibhav//Desktop");
                    commandParams.put("params", params);
                    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
                    String command = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(commandParams);
                    String u = driverService.getUrl().toString() + "/session/" + driver.getSessionId() + "/chromium/send_command";
                    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(u);
                    request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
                    request.setEntity(new StringEntity(command));
                    httpClient.execute(request);
            driver.get("http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/");
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("32 bit Windows IE")).click();
```

Comment: Could you please explain this code? it doesn't work. May be i am using it incorrectly.

Comment: The code basically enables/allows downloadBehaviour on the page. And sets a download path for the file where it shall be downloaded. Rest of code is simple selenium code

Comment: import com.jayway.restassured.mapper.ObjectMapper;
Please find the errors that i m getting while using this import
-> Cannot iniatiate Type ObjectMapper (@line ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper)

please confirm all my other imports are right or not:
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;

Comment: import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper; @GunaYuvan

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a recent version of Chrome (104). But I realized the problem was that **a file with the same name** was present in the download folder.

When I clear the folder and launch the test again, I can see that the file is well downloaded in the folder.